# Set up a VBA Macro that will create a new sheet for every line of info in my main worksheet and laid out in a certain format?

Tags: vba, excel

The format of the sheet that has the info is as follows...

```
Project#     Project Name       Item#1     Item#2     Item#3      Item#4    Item#5    Item#6
```

I want to name the new worksheet after the Project Name. I figured the easiest way to set up the new worksheet under the desired format is to have one worksheet already set up, copy all info from one row into this worksheet and then copy that into a new worksheet with the project name.

I set up a For Each Loop to determine whether there is a Project Name and if so, create the new sheet with the copied format from the other worksheet. My problem is that I can't figure out how to get all the other cells on that line copied to the new worksheet.

Can I use some kind of offset to copy the rest of the fields? I guess I don't understand how to know which cell is active to do that. Did I mention I'm pretty inexperienced with VBA?

I imagine there's probably many other ways to do this other than a For Each Loop and I am in no way against starting over so any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Here's the code I have that just creates the new worksheets but now I'm just stuck...

```
Sub Create_Certificate()

    For Each ProjectName In Worksheets("Paste").Range("H6:H104")

    If ProjectName <> "" Then
        Sheets("Do Not Modify").Copy After:=Sheets("Do Not Modify")
        ActiveSheet.Name = ProjectName
    End If

    Next ProjectName

End Sub
```

Just wanted to share my finished product in case someone else runs into this situation...

```
Sub Create_Certificate()

For Each ProjectName In Worksheets("Paste").Range("H6:H104")

If ProjectName <> "" Then
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("G7").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("G" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("H20").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("H" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D14").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("I" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D13").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("J" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D11").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("K" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D12").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("L" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D16").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("M" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Range("D15").Value = Sheets("Paste").Range("N" & ProjectName.Row).Value
    Sheets("Do Not Modify").Copy After:=Sheets("Do Not Modify")
    ActiveSheet.Name = ProjectName
End If

Next ProjectName

End Sub
```

Comment: So, we're dealing with 2 formats, actually: one of the destination sheet (that is newly created), and one of the "Paste" sheet. What you've shown in the start of your post is the format of the "Paste" worksheet, right? So, this begs the question: what is the format of the newly created sheet? (which is the same as the format of "Do Not Modify" sheet). More directly: where exactly you want the information written in the new sheet?

Comment: Yes the "Paste" worksheet is where the reports that I receive will be pasted into a table in the format above. The "Do Not Modify" sheet is set up as a certificate. The values from the "Paste" sheet will be in various ranges on the new sheet. I couldn't really post the certificate because I didn't want to give away too much information about my company. I think I should be able to modify any generic ranges to copy the values to the correct cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the row of the cell with the project name with `ProjectName.Row` and use that to copy ranges from the `Paste` sheet.

```
Sheets("" & ProjectName & "").Range("A2:E2").Value = _
    Sheets("Paste").Range( _
    "F" & ProjectName.Row & ":" & "J" & ProjectName.Row).Value
```

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!